# could you explain me the logic behind this code

Tags: java

> Can you please explain me logic behind this code

```
System.out.print((char)((c[z]%26)+97));
```

Comment: On its own it does nothing unless you tell us what `c` and `z` look like

Comment: there is no logic behind the code apart from compilation errors https://ideone.com/UaugBi  `cannot find symbol c and z`

Comment: @singhakash Your statement is incorrect. There is most certainly a logic behind this code. You have to declare the array and put it into a loop using z as an index.

Comment: @EvanBechtol check the ideone link

Comment: @singhakash You didn't populate the array or even declare it in your link.

Comment: @EvanBechtol thats what I am saying he dint initiliaze c and z

Comment: @singhakash  He only pasted one line asking for an explanation of how it works, it's safe to assume that he has it working. His question doesn't involve how to get it to execute, simply logical explanation.

Comment: @EvanBechtol he is asking for help without giving proper information.How can we assume there are hundread of assumptions

Comment: @singhakash "logic" != "why won't this work"

Comment: @EvanBechtol why thisquestion = downvate++

Comment: @EvanBechtol I also dint downvote it waiting for him to edit

Answer (score 1):

It prints a letter between `a` and `z` depending on the value of `c[z]`.

`c[z]%26` gives you an integer between 0 and 25.

`97` is the numeric value of `a`.

Adding the two and casting to `char` gives a letter between `a` and `z`.

Answer (score 0):

- Get z-th element from array c (which is *probably* an int).
- Modulo 26 gives you value from 0-25
- Add 97 (which is int value of small letter a)

Answer (score 0):

It will print the character between a-z. The way it works is:

- x[z]%26 will return you number between 0-25
- You are adding that number to 97. Ascii value of numbers between 97-125 represents a-z characters.
- Post adding you are type casting it to character which is what gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This code prints out a single line, not ended by a new-line character; The next line to be printed will appear on this line as well.

It first typecasts the data as a `char`.
Then it access the data in the index `z`of the array `c`. 
`c[z]`.
It takes this data and does a modulus operator on it. The modulus operator returns the remainder in the division process.

Once this is done, `97` is added to that value.
This then prints the `char` associated with the ascii value. Since we are adding 97, it will be a lowercase letter from `a-z`.

Example: Passing this data returns the lowercase letter 'b'

```
    public static void main (String [] args) {
    int [] c = new int [1];
    c[0] = 27;
    System.out.print((char)((c[0]%26)+97));
}
```